# How can i display a screen when I open an app

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, mobile, expo

So basically I want to display an screen when opening an app(ex. Twitter) and then after the user completes x task let them get into the app

Something similar of how applocks work. So I wanted to ask you all if you know how can I make this using react native, flutter or if I have to implement it using kotlin

Edit: This is what I want to do:I want to make an app where you need to complete a puzzle before entering an app like Twitter or Instagram so you delay the entry. Im a student and this will just be a side project

Thank you for ur time c:

Ive trying to get a way of doing this but I have no actual idea of how can I manage to get this working

Comment: Nooo, that's not what I want to do. I want to make an app where you need to complete a puzzle before entering an app like Twitter or Instagram so you delay the entry. Im a student and this will just be a side project

Comment: Your app cannot control my entry into an app you didn't put in the store, unless I'm on a device that your company manages.

Comment: No, currently flutter does not support this type of functionality, you need to do it with kotlin there are several tutorials available out there on youtube and other websites. You can take help from there

Comment: @JunaidKhalid You can't do it in Kotlin either.  There is no API to prevent another, separate app from running.  Nor should there be, the main purpose of that would be ransomeware.

Comment: @GabeSechan Then how applock apps are working? They are loking the apps with user consent aren't they?

Comment: @JunaidKhalid You can write your own desktop app and make it hard to get to the app itself.  That could then insert something in the middle, if launched from the home screen.  But even then there's always a way around it (launch it from settings).  But most apps like that just don't work and are hosts for trojans.

Comment: I've seen some apps do this. Like I said before, the app lock. Obviously this behavior will just happen when the user: 1. Agrees 2.Chooses which apps he wants to delay entrance. Basically I want to solve a problem: Social media scrolling hell and procrastination